# Python pycaw AudioUtilities change volume of program by it's PID instead of name

Tags: python

I set up a program that can change the volume of a specific program by it's name but I need to change it by the programs PID.

Here's my code for changing the volume. I thought I could change the .name() to .pid() or something but it doesn't work. When I do the .pid() i get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
def changeVolume(newVolume, program):
sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
for session in sessions:
    volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(ISimpleAudioVolume)
    if session.Process and session.Process.name().lower() == program + ".exe":
        volume.SetMasterVolume(newVolume, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.pid` instead of `.pid()`?

I think .pid would work, but since it might just be an integer, calling it as a method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but you can use session.ProcessId which will give you access to the Process Id.